# Как пройтись по элементам различающимся в id на порядковую единицу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть набор классов c `id` различающимися на порядковый номер единицы.

Как произвести с ними одновременно какие-либо манипуляции, к примеру добавить класс `foo`.

**ВАЖНО:** не правя `html` при этом

```js
$( "#id1" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">text 1</div>
<div id="id2">text 2</div>
<div id="id3">text 3</div>
...
<div id="id100">text 100</div>
```

Comment: Надо дать им общий класс и работать через него: `$('.bar').addClass('foo');`

Comment: @u_mulder я не просил упрощать поставленную проблему, вмешиваться в `html` нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [селекторах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) возможны условные выражения

```js
$("[id^=id]").addClass('foo').css('background-color', 'wheat')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">text 1</div>
<div id="id2">text 2</div>
<div id="id3">text 3</div>
<div id="id4">text 4</div>
<div id="id5">text 5</div>
```

тут селектор выбирает все элементы id которых начинается со строки `id`

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз нельзя, то:

```
$("div[id^='id']").addClass("foo");
```